# Change https back to http on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I recently had to reinstall my solution in Visual Studio for Mac. When I clicked run for the first time it asked for my system password to trust an SSL certificate. I clicked yes. Now the solution runs on localhost port 5001 instead of 5000 and is using https instead of http. I am now getting mixed content errors on my HttpRequests. How do I change it back to http and port 5000. This is Visual Studio Mac Community 8.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just removed the reference to https://localhost:5001 in the ASP.Net Core run configuration found in Project Options and it was back to normal.

[image]